# Jquery set maxdate as mindate+5 days not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a datepicker with startdate should be next sunday.The maxdate should be 5 days from sunday .Fridays and saturdays should not be selected.So if date is today(22 jan 2017),29th jan,30th jan,31st jan,feb1 ,feb2 should only be selected by the user.

My code is like this.

```
var values = '29-01-2017'.split("-"); //Default date
var parsed_date = new Date(values[2], values[1]-1, values[0]);
alert(parsed_date);
$(".DueDate").datepicker({
    minDate:parsed_date,//
    maxDate:parsed_date +'+1w', // 5 business days
    beforeShowDay: function(date){
        var day = date.getDay();
        return [(day != 5 && day != 6 )];
    }, // disable weekends
    dateFormat : 'mm/dd/yy',
    changeMonth : true,
    changeYear : true,
    defaultDate: new Date(),
    setDate : new Date()
});
```

This is not working properly

Answer (score 0):

After
var parsed_date = new Date(values[2], values[1]-1, values[0]);

write

parsed_date.setDate(parsed_date.getDate()+5);

it will add 5 days to the date stored in parsed_date object
now you can set maxDate of date picker like this

maxDate: parsed_date

Hope this helps

Comment: I have tried this one,but this will make all 5 days of the week after the minDate is allowed for selection